# Embed an anonymous text editor on website

Tags: javascript, html

I am embedding an [anonymous text editor based on Writeurl IP](http://www.writeurl.com/text/fon5o6gtr3gh9gsl7kb2/g4xhwwdi34hm19w9fcpm/ppnx1ye1kl6unk10ov08) on my website following instructions given [here](http://www.writeurl.com/embed) There is some mistake, please help to clear...

```js
nbe.site.embed_write(element or DOM id, {
 id : 'fon5o6gtr3gh9gsl7kb2',
 read : 'g4xhwwdi34hm19w9fcpm',
 write : 'ppnx1ye1kl6unk10ov08'
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.writeurl.com/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://www.writeurl.com/script.js"></script>
<body>

<h1>Embed www.writeurl.com in HTML</h1>

<span id='fon5o6gtr3gh9gsl7kb2'>Test</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are your external files loaded in the correct place? do you have a js conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Andrei Deinichenko,

The problem is that you did not specify an element or ID in the JS part of the code.

You should replace the "**element or DOM id**" part with an element or DOM id you use below which in your case is the **span id** -> `<span id='fon5o6gtr3gh9gsl7kb2'>Test</span>`

Therefore, the JS part of the code should look like this:

```
nbe.site.embed_write(fon5o6gtr3gh9gsl7kb2, {
        id : 'fon5o6gtr3gh9gsl7kb2',
        read : 'g4xhwwdi34hm19w9fcpm',
        write : 'ppnx1ye1kl6unk10ov08' 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be id can be replaced with 'test'

```js
nbe.site.embed_write(test, {
 id : 'fon5o6gtr3gh9gsl7kb2',
 read : 'g4xhwwdi34hm19w9fcpm',
 write : 'ppnx1ye1kl6unk10ov08'
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.writeurl.com/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://www.writeurl.com/script.js"></script>
<body>

<h1>Embed www.writeurl.com in HTML</h1>

<span id='test'>Test</span>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
nbe.site.embed_write(element or DOM id, {
 id : 'fon5o6gtr3gh9gsl7kb2',
 read : 'g4xhwwdi34hm19w9fcpm',
 write : 'ppnx1ye1kl6unk10ov08'
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.writeurl.com/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://www.writeurl.com/script.js"></script>
<body>

<h1>Embed www.writeurl.com in HTML</h1>

<span id='fon5o6gtr3gh9gsl7kb2'>Test</span>

</body>
</html>
```